# Example of application of limit in daily life

Tags: limits

We know that concept of limit plays a central role in calculus.I had find information in internet about the application of concept of limit in daily life but unfortunately I failed to find it. Can anyone give examples?

For instance, the derivative, integral and continuity require the concept of limit. I wonder is there any other application in daily life or certain field.

Answer (score 1):

1. A derivative is a limit.
2. Speed is the derivative of position
3. We use the concept of speed everyday.

Therefore, without knowing, we use the concept of limits everyday.

Or, maybe a more technical answer, when Google is calculating the PageRank of a website, it is actually calculating the stationary distribution of a random process, and this stationary distribution is actually the limit of some sequence of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

For example the area of a circle can be calculated as a limit of areas of (regular, equilateral) polygons drawn inside the circle. The limit is that you send the number of vertices to infinity to approximate the circle as best as possible.